# How do I align broken up equations?

Tags: pdftex

How do I align subequations with text in between?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Foo.

\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:f}
    \begin{aligned}
        A &=10000000000000000 + -1 + -10000000000000000000000 \\
        &= 10000000000000000000000  + 10000000000000000000000 + -1
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:oo}
    \begin{aligned}
        A &=10000000000000000 + -1 + -100000000000 \\
        &= 1 + 10000000000000000000000 + -1
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Bar.

\begin{equation} \label{eq:ar}
    \begin{aligned}
        A &=1 + -1 + -1 \\
        &= 1 + 1 + -1
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

Foobar.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean all pairs of  aligned (sub)equations should be aligned globally at the `=` sign?

Comment: Yes, all equations aligned with eachother, despite text in between

Comment: The text  in between is no problem, the real problem is the set of nested `aligned` – unless you accept the numbering of  a pair be on the upper or on the lower equation level, not centred.

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite the code to achieve alignment without the nested parts?

Comment: Yes, but the equation numbers won't be vertically centred w.r.t. pairs of grouped equations

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possibility, with a single `align` environment  and `\intertext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent Foo.
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
        A &=10000000000000000 + -1 + -10000000000000000000000 \notag\\
        &= 10000000000000000000000 + 10000000000000000000000 + -1 \label{eq:f} \\[1ex]
        A &=10000000000000000 + -1 + -100000000000 \notag\\
        &= 1 + 10000000000000000000000 + -1 \label{eq:oo} \\[1ex]
\shortintertext{Bar. \vskip 1ex}
        A &=1 + -1 + -1 \notag \\
        &= 1 + 1 + -1 \label{eq:ar}
\end{align}
Foobar.
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]